# Sum the values between the dict

Tags: python, dictionary

**GOAL:**

I am trying to sum the values ​​between dict ct_db and ct_db2 whenever the keys are the same.

**Example:**

RR-00 == RR-00, so make 14 + 223

**Problem:**

All dict keys are not being compared, the operation is terminated as soon as the dict is traversed, but since the keys are out of order, the correct calculations are not made.

**SCRIPT:**

```
ct_db = {u'AB-00 ': 18, u'RR-00': 14, u'LD-00 ': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00 ': 452}
ct_db2 = {u'CD-07 ': 26, u'RR-00': 223, u'LD-00 ': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00 ': 11}

not_installed = []
for elemA, elemB in zip (ct_db, ct_db2):
        if (elemA == elemB):
                print ("MATCH" + elemA + "-" + elemB)
                not_installed.append (ct_db [elemA] + ct_db2 [elemB])
        else:
                print ("NOT MATCH" + elemA + "-" + elemB)

print (not_installed)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
NOT MATCH LD-00 - CD-07
NOT MATCH SR-00 - LD-00
NOT MATCH AB-00 - RR-00
NOT MATCH RR-00 - IA-00
NOT MATCH YT-00 - SR-00
[]
```

Comment: You don't have to iterate through both. Since you only care about the intersection of the dicts, you can iterate through one, check if `key in dict2` (which is a cheap O(1) operation) and keep your `if/else` logic

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: show me an excerpt of what it would look like please

Comment: Version Python 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is simple: Find the common keys between the two dictionaries and calculate the sum. In Python 3, the `dict.keys()` method returns a set-like object, therefore we can use the `&` operator to find the intersection between two sets of keys:

```
ct_db = {u'AB-00 ': 18, u'RR-00': 14, u'LD-00 ': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00 ': 452}
ct_db2 = {u'CD-07 ': 26, u'RR-00': 223, u'LD-00 ': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00 ': 11}

print(ct_db)
print(ct_db2)

common_keys = ct_db.keys() & ct_db2.keys()
not_installed = {k: ct_db[k] + ct_db2[k] for k in common_keys}
print(not_installed)
```

Output:

```
{'AB-00 ': 18, 'RR-00': 14, 'LD-00 ': 56, 'SR-00': 33, 'YT-00 ': 452}
{'CD-07 ': 26, 'RR-00': 223, 'LD-00 ': 367, 'SR-00': 257, 'IA-00 ': 11}
{'SR-00': 290, 'LD-00 ': 423, 'RR-00': 237}
```

## Update

If you are only interested in the sums, then use `not_installed.values()`

Answer (score 5):

You only need to iterate over the keys of one of the dicts, and check if each key is in the other dict:

```
not_installed = []

for elem in ct_db:
    if elem in ct_db2:
        not_installed.append(ct_db[elem] + ct_db2[elem])

print(not_installed)
```

Output:

```
[237, 423, 290]
```

Comment: @MrGeek's code is correct. If a key is in `ct_db2` only, it should not be counted.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
ct_db = {u'AB-00 ': 18, u'RR-00': 14, u'LD-00 ': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00 ': 452}
ct_db2 = {u'CD-07 ': 26, u'RR-00': 223, u'LD-00 ': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00 ': 11}

counter = collections.Counter(ct_db)
counter += ct_db2
# >>> counter 
# Counter({'YT-00 ': 452, 'LD-00 ': 423, 'SR-00': 290, 'RR-00': 237, 'CD-07 ': 26, 'AB-00 ': 18, 'IA-00 ': 11})

# And if you want only the overlapping keys:
overlapping_keys = ct_db.keys() & ct_db2.keys()
counter = {k: v for k, v in counter.items() if k in overlapping_keys}
# >>> counter
# {'RR-00': 237, 'LD-00 ': 423, 'SR-00': 290}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a dictionary comprehension is a neat alternative way.

Given two dictionaries `d1` and `d2`:

```
output = {k: d1[k] + d2[k] for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys()}
```

The expression `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` takes advantage of `set` intersection available on `dict_keys` objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the intersection property of sets in this case
as used in examples here https://howtodoinjava.com/python/dictionary-intersection/

```py
ct_db = {u'AB-00 ': 18, u'RR-00': 14,
         u'LD-00 ': 56, u'SR-00': 33, u'YT-00 ': 452}

ct_db2 = {u'CD-07 ': 26, u'RR-00': 223,
          u'LD-00 ': 367, u'SR-00': 257, u'IA-00 ': 11}

not_installed = []

ct_set = set(ct_db)

ct_set2 = set(ct_db2)

for name in ct_set.intersection(ct_set2):
    #print(name) to see the common keys
    not_installed.append(ct_db[name] + ct_db2[name])

print(not_installed)
```